# Can I create a Mavericks installation in VMWare Fusion and migrate that to the native disk?

Tags: macos, vmware, migration

My current installation has become kind of cluttered and I want to create a fresh one in VMWare. When the one in VMWare has everything I need, I'd like to migrate it to the native disk, so it become my main (normal) OS.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Time Machine backup from within the VM and use this to restore the native machine once you've re-installed OS X there..

I do not know if all drivers are installed at all times (doesn't happen for Windows) so I would be a bit wary of using cloned disks to do this.  Much rather let Time Machine do what it is designed for.

Comment: @Mark VMWare emulates a HFS disk so I don't think this should be an issue.

Comment: I did this the other way around a couple of months ago.  I was retiring some older hardware but I still needed the OS, so I backed it up to TM, then booted a new VM by mounting a 10.9 installation disc image.  I was easily able to restore the TM backup to the VM.